# How to distribute power to multiple devices on a PCB

Tags: power, pcb, pcb-design

I am new to hobby level PCB's, but looking at taking my projects to the next step moving from breadboard. The part I do not know how to do, or see on tutorials is how do I take a single 5V line (or any voltage line), and distribute it across multiple devices/sensors.

So for example, I have a single regulated 5V line (coming from a 12V to 5V converter), and I want to send it to the PCB, and then from the PCB I want to take the 5V line and send it to my arduino (5V GPIO in), Rasperry Pi (5V GPIO in), and a couple other devices.

Do I solder across joints, seems like asking for trouble? Is there a component, or techinque for doing this?

Comment: Are you designing a custom PCB? Or do you want to hand-wire a prototype PCB? A prototype PCB is generic without any traces, you do the wiring yourself. You can also use a perf-board without any copper, but prototype PCBs are so cheap now they are usually better.

Comment: @Mattman944 I am doing a custom/prototype PCB, using the hobby pcb boards like so. So I send 5V into one of the pins/holes, and need to get it to another 3 or more. https://www.amazon.com/DEYUE-Double-sided-Prototyping-Solder-able-Protoboards/dp/B07FFDFLZ3/ref=sr_1_4?crid=39M40A0A1RMMJ&dchild=1&keywords=pcb+board&qid=1603549637&sprefix=pcb+%2Caps%2C200&sr=8-4

Comment: @user2840470 Do you mean as described in the answers at [How do I do point to point wiring on a protoboard?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24017/how-do-i-do-point-to-point-wiring-on-a-protoboard) Also, you can get protoboard with some of the holes connected together in threes or fives, etc.

Comment: You solder joints. Get good enough at soldering and it's no trouble.

Comment: @Brian Drummond No. Solder joints on a perforated board are difficult to do and not reliable unless you pour a large load of tin. I always add a short bit if wire to join two holes. I suffered enough before by not doing so.

Comment: @Fredled Apparently he's talking about some kind of perfboard (different from the UK's Veroboard) so  you are right. That was totally unclear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

When wiring a prototype PCB, I use bare solid wire to make the connections. I use 24 AWG for most connections. Sometimes I use 20 AWG or 16 AWG for ground and power buses, or high current paths. You can probably use 24 AWG for everything. 24 AWG is a personal preference, you could probably use a slightly smaller wire for your project.

For components with long leads, like resistors and capacitors, you can often stretch the component lead to the destination.

The connecting wire should be wrapped around the protruding lead to make a solid mechanical connection before soldering.

[image]